# what should rolesessioname be set to when redeeming cognito open id token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to exchange the open id token from cognito for a valid aws token using `cognito.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` and `sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity`

What should I set the RoleSessionName required property to for the sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity call?  I don't set it anywhere during the open id call.

Is this just an arbitrary string?  Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RoleSessionName parameter is used to distinguish unique "end-user sessions" or continuation of a single session that may be longer than the maximum time allowed for your role credentials.

A combination of AWS account, credentials, and the RoleSessionName is used to uniquely identify a single "end-user session". Using the same RoleSessionName between 2 different AWS accounts is safe and won't cross-match sessions.

Since the sessions won't cross-match between AWS accounts, it may be safe to use a constant value all the time. However, there may be unintended side-effects if the same user is using your app twice at the same time.

A randomly generated string (like a GUID) is a good place to start, and in many cases will be sufficient.

However, there are cases where you will need to re-use a RoleSessionName. For example, let's say you were uploading a very large file using S3 multi-part upload. Multi-part uploads have a requirement that all parts be uploaded by the same "owner". The AWS account and even the credentials (IAM user) are not "owner enough". They must also use the same RoleSessionName.

When you "assume role", your credentials have an expiry date. If your upload will take longer than that expiry date, you'll need to "assume role" again and re-use the RoleSessionName. This tells AWS that the following uploads are owned by the same session as the previous ones.